# jQuery datatables buttons defaults

Tags: datatables, default-value, datatables-1.10, datatable-buttons

I have some styles that I need to apply to all DataTables buttons so that they match the rest of the buttons on my site.  I can add that using [the `className` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.className) as below, but I'd like not to have to supply the same thing every time.

Manual example

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'I look like a button',
      className: 'icanhazdefalt'
    }
  ]
})
```

I see in the docs that the default value is `undefined`.  I couldn't find anywhere in the docs that you could override the default for this or other options.  Is this possible? Something like:

```
$.fn.DataTable.Buttons.options.extend({
  className: 'icanhazdefalt'
})
```

What I need is to be able to set the default for the plugin itself (rather than for a specific instance).  Then all instances I create on the page from then on would have the default I specified.  I can include the script that sets the default right after the plugin script (perhaps in a layout file) so that I never have to manually do anything to get all subsequent instances to have the default className (but still be able to override it by explicitly providing it as shown in the 'manual example' above).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: {
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'copy', className: 'copyButton' },
            { extend: 'excel', className: 'excelButton' }
        ]
    }
} );
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.className

**EDIT:** There might be a better and simpler way of doing this but, this is what I came up at the moment.

```
//DataTable
var table= $("#myTable").DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'I look like a button'
        },
        {
            text: 'I dont'
        }
    ]
} );

//Add class to all buttons
$(table.buttons()).each(function(){
    $($(this)[0]["node"]).addClass("sampleClass");
});
```

You can also change your button selection by giving a parameter for buttons().
See this [link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons()) for that.

Comment: The link you provided is the same URL as the one in the question.  The example you give is similar to the one in the question.  What I'm really after is how to avoid having to do that every time by setting a default that it will use every time (unless overridden by something specified in the buttons `className` option on a per-instance basis).